# How can I write this complex query SQL?

Tags: mysql

If I know how to filter by all signs of the zodiac, then by the sign of the zodiac 'Capricorn' (from December 22 to January 20) I do not know how to select.

Here is the structure of the tables, do I need to select all users with the sign of the zodiac 'Capricorn'?

The structure of the tables can be changed (or even add new tables if required):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horoscope` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `date_start` VARCHAR(5),
    `date_end` VARCHAR(5)
);
CREATE INDEX `horoscope_idx_1` ON `horoscope`(`date_start`, `date_end`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `birthday` DATE NOT NULL
);
```

**Insert test data**

```
# Insert horoscope in table
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Aries', '03-21', '04-20');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Taurus', '04-21', '05-20');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Gemini', '05-22', '06-21');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Cancer', '06-22', '07-22');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Leo', '07-23', '08-23');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Virgin', '08-24', '09-22');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Libra', '08-23', '10-22');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Scorpio', '10-23', '11-21');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Sagittarius', '11-22', '12-21');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Capricorn', '12-22', '01-20');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Aquarius', '01-21', '02-19');
INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`name`, `date_start`, `date_end`) VALUES ('Pisces', '02-20', '03-20');

# Insert random user in table
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_user`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_user`(IN `count_user` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'A procedure for inserting random user'

BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM `user`
        ORDER BY `id` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    );
    IF i IS NULL
        THEN SET i = 1;
    END IF;

    SET `count_user` = `count_user` + i;

    WHILE i <= `count_user` DO
        SET @`name` = CONCAT('user_', i);
        SET @`user_birth` = '1980-01-01' + INTERVAL (RAND() * 365 * 20) DAY;

        INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `birthday`) VALUES (@`name`, @`user_birth`);

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
CALL `add_user`(1000);
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_user`;
```

Comment: Hello, how do you asign the user it’s zodiac sign? Is it a trigger or a function?

Comment: Hey. I do not assign a star sign to the user. I need to know by date what is the sign of the zodiac

Comment: If **A** user has **A** birth sign then it makes sense to store this against the user. It would be less efficient to filter by date each and every time you need this information. The only way that filtering by date would make sense is if the zodiac date boundaries "moved"

Answer (score 0):

**I decided =)**

```
SELECT *
FROM user as u
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(u.birthday, '%m%d') >= (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(LEFT(`h`.`date_start`, 2), RIGHT(`h`.`date_start`, 2))
        FROM horoscope h
        WHERE h.name = 'Capricorn'
    ) AND DATE_FORMAT(u.birthday, '%m%d') <= 1231
) OR (
    DATE_FORMAT(u.birthday, '%m%d') >= 101 AND DATE_FORMAT(u.birthday, '%m%d') <= (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(LEFT(`h`.`date_end`, 2), RIGHT(`h`.`date_end`, 2))
        FROM horoscope h
        WHERE h.name = 'Capricorn'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the boundaries of each zodiac sign are fixed dates, then it would make sense to add birth-sign as an attribute to each user instead of filtering by dates each and every time you need that information.

However I would suggest the following if you do need to filter:

```
select *
from user u
inner join horoscope h
where (h.date_start > h.date_end 
       and u.birthday between str_to_date(concat(year(u.birthday)-1, h.date_start),'%Y%m-%d')
                          and str_to_date(concat(year(u.birthday), h.date_end),'%Y%m-%d')
   )
or (h.date_start < h.date_end 
    and u.birthday between str_to_date(concat(year(u.birthday), h.date_start),'%Y%m-%d')
                       and str_to_date(concat(year(u.birthday), h.date_end),'%Y%m-%d')
   )
```

Note however that the indexing of the 2 varchar(5) columns in horoscope probably isn't going to be helpful to your queries.

see:  https://rextester.com/OAOTEH65480